# Replacing navigation bar text with images?

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, navigationbar

I'm currently trying to figure out the best way to replace my current navigation bar menu (that has both a hover effect and drop-down menu) with images instead of having text as links.  I want to have the same effects I have currently, but hide the text and use the images instead.

Comment: Just insert images using an `<img>` tag? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Images as menu links seems pretty old school to me...and probably poor SEO and accessibility-wise too.

Comment: I tried doing something along the lines of: <li class='has-sub'><a href='#' <img src="" alt="" ></a></li> etc etc but that didn't seem to work.

Comment: @Pauli_D - this isn't for a main website so SEO isn't really needed.  Besides, isn't there a way to just hide the text and use images?  Would that affect seo?

Answer (score 0):

To have the text present but not visible, the simplest way is to use the follow two rules in the relevant rules:

```
text-indent: -1000em;
overflow: hidden;
```

This will move the text outside the bounds of the element where it will be invisible, leaving only the background image.

Comment: Wouldn't this also move the bounds of the hover and drop-down menu effects as well?  The goal here is to have the new images able to be hovered over and the drop-down menu to prompt.

Comment: No. It only indents the text.

Answer (score 0):

Your css is really rough. You are way over-qualifying everything and repeating styles everywhere. I suggest cleaning all that up. But in the meantime, in your css, add:

```
#cssmenu a {
    text-indent: -9999px;
}
```

Comment: Tried this, it seems to be also hiding my drop-down menu and shrunk the hover space of both the main navigation effects and the size of the drop down menu. Is the shrinkage simply because there is no text to stretch it or?

Comment: Yes. You will need to do some rewriting to the css, but ultimately this is what you want to use.